# react-redux connect with Formik - Maximum call stack size exceeded

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux, formik

I get an infinite loop when i try to connect my form component to redux.
Would be funny if it wasn't frustrating because the code worked earlier today and now it doesn't after i reverted 1 commit.

Code was the same pretty much the same and connect()() worked and i had signUserUp function available as prop to work with. I removed node_modules and package-lock just in case and install all again and it's the same.

**Signup.js**

```
import { connect } from "react-redux";
import signupActions from "../modules/signup";

function Signup() {
  return <BasicForm />
}

const BasicForm = () => (
  <Formik
    initialValues={{ email: "", password: "", confirmPassword: "" }}
    validationSchema={signupSchema}
    onSubmit={(values, actions) => {
      console.log("form data: ", values);
    }}
    render={({ values, errors, touched, isSubmitting, handleChange, handleBlur, handleSubmit }) => (
      <Container>
        <Form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
          <Form.Input
            type="text"
            placeholder="Email"
            onChange={handleChange}
            onBlur={handleBlur}
            value={values.email}
            name="email"
          />
          {errors.email && touched.email && <div>{errors.email}</div>}

          <Form.Input
            type="password"
            placeholder="Password"
            onChange={handleChange}
            onBlur={handleBlur}
            value={values.password}
            name="password"
          />
          {errors.password && touched.password && <div>{errors.password}</div>}

          <Form.Input
            type="password"
            placeholder="Confirm Password"
            onChange={handleChange}
            onBlur={handleBlur}
            value={values.confirmPassword}
            name="confirmPassword"
          />
          {errors.confirmPassword && touched.confirmPassword && <div>{errors.confirmPassword}</div>}

          <Button primary type="submit" onSubmit={handleSubmit} disabled={isSubmitting}>
            Submit
          </Button>
        </Form>
      </Container>
    )}
  />
);

export default connect(
  null,
  signupActions
)(Signup);
```

i get the error here obviously when i add connect...

This is the single file module with redux stuff
**signup.js**

```
import api from '../utils/api';

const SIGN_UP = 'signup/SIGN_UP';

const initialState = {
  isAuthenticated: false,
  jwt: '',
  authError: '',
  formErrors: [],
};

export default (state = initialState, action = {}) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case SIGN_UP:
      return { ...state, isAuthenticated: true, jwt: action.payload, authError: '', formErrors: [] };
    default:
      return state;
  }
};

export const signup = token => ({
  type: SIGN_UP,
  payload: token,
});

export const signUserUp = credentials => {
  return dispatch => api.post('auth/signup', credentials).then(token => dispatch(signup(token)));
};
```

In **rootReducer.js** i import that signupReducer like this

```
import signupReducer from './modules/signup';

export default combineReducers({
  signup: signupReducer,
});
```

here is the [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/mqr4yrymvx) example to see the errors at least when i try to visit sign up page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem was how you were applying `signupActions` (which was default exported as the `reducer` and not an `action creator`) to `connect`.

Working example (which includes the notes below): https://codesandbox.io/s/4rook7ryv4

---

**Notes:**

Separate your `containers` from your `components`: https://medium.com/@dan_abramov/smart-and-dumb-components-7ca2f9a7c7d0

Separate your `actions`, `reducers` and `types`.

I've restructured your application to be easier to understand/read. I'd highly recommend that you use this flow and structure listed below (or, if you want to be more modular with your components/views, bundle everything related to that component/view together into a single folder -- this would be better if you're working within a large team).

```
├── build
|   ├── css
|   |   ├── main.[contenthash:8].css
|   |   └── main.[contenthash:8].css.map
|   ├── js
|   |   ├── main.[hash].js
|   |   └── main.[hash].js.map
|   ├── media
|   |   └── [hash].[ext]
|   └── favicon.ico
|   └── index.html
|
├── public
|   ├── favicon.ico
|   └── index.html
|
├── src
|   ├── actions
|   ├── components
|   ├── containers
|   ├── images
|   ├── reducers
|   ├── routes
|   ├── store
|   ├── styles
|   ├── tests
|   ├── types
|   ├── utils
|   ├── views
|   ├── index.js
|   ├── serviceWorker.js
|   └── setupTests.js
|
├── .eslintrc
├── .gitignore
├── README.md
├── package.lock.json
└── package.json
```

Comment: I guess i never liked the idea of having things in folders like that: reducers, containers, components, actions etc, i prefered separating by feature like auth or users or post etc. Thanks for your help and effort and sorry for the late response